# multiuser chat App with Pomelo server built with tidesdk not working

Tags: node.js, tidesdk

I tried to build with tideSDK a windows standalone client for a multiuser Pomelo chat app
(Pomelo is a game server framework for node.js: http://pomelo.netease.com/) .

I took the web-server/public of pomelo project folder as ressources file.
Before building, i launched pomelo server and tested the files by opening directly ressources/index.html into my browser => all was ok.

Then i launched (and later build) the app in tideSDK, but nothing happens when i click on "join" button.

Here is the console log from tideSDK :

at launch :

```
[09:32:29:535] [Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module:
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\ win32\app\1.3.1-beta\tideapp.dll
[09:32:29:568] [Ti.App.AppConfig] [Debug] Loading config file:
M:\Tiry\travail\d
ev-pomelo\tideSDK\standalone-chatpomelo\dist\win32\standalone-chatpomelo\tiapp.x
ml [09:32:29:577] [Ti.App] [Debug] Loaded config file successfully
[09:32:29:582] [Ti.Host] [Information] Loaded module = app
[09:32:29:585] [Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module:
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\ win32\codec\1.3.1-beta\tidecodec.dll
[09:32:29:602] [Ti.Host] [Information] Loaded module = codec
[09:32:29:606] [Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module:
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\database\1.3.1-beta\tidedatabase.dll [09:32:29:636] [Ti.Host]
[Information] Loaded module = database [09:32:29:641] [Ti.Host]
[Debug] Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\filesystem\1.3.1-beta\tidefilesystem.dll [09:32:29:653]
[Ti.Host] [Information] Loaded module = filesystem [09:32:29:658]
[Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\media\1.3.1-beta\tidemedia.dll [09:32:29:667] [Ti.Host]
[Information] Loaded module = media [09:32:29:671] [Ti.Host] [Debug]
Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\monkey\1.3.1-beta\tidemonkey.dll [09:32:29:681] [Ti.Host]
[Information] Loaded module = monkey [09:32:29:685] [Ti.Host] [Debug]
Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\network\1.3.1-beta\tidenetwork.dll [09:32:29:731] [Ti.Host]
[Information] Loaded module = network [09:32:29:738] [Ti.Host] [Debug]
Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\platform\1.3.1-beta\tideplatform.dll [09:32:29:760] [Ti.Host]
[Information] Loaded module = platform [09:32:29:764] [Ti.Host]
[Debug] Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\process\1.3.1-beta\tideprocess.dll [09:32:29:777] [Ti.Host]
[Information] Loaded module = process [09:32:29:783] [Ti.Host] [Debug]
Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\ui\1.3.1-beta\tideui.dll [09:32:29:798] [Ti.Host] [Information]
Loaded module = ui [09:32:29:802] [Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module:
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\ win32\worker\1.3.1-beta\tideworker.dll
[09:32:29:813] [Ti.Host] [Information] Loaded module = worker
[09:32:29:818] [Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module:
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\filesystem\1.3.1-beta\tifilesystemmodule.js [09:32:29:825]
[Ti.JavaScript] [Information] Loading JS path=C:\ProgramData\Tide
SDK\modules\win32\filesystem\1.3.1-beta\tifilesystemmodule.js
[09:32:29:837] [Ti.Host] [Information] Loaded module = tifilesystem
[09:32:29:841] [Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module:
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\network\1.3.1-beta\tinetworkmodule.js [09:32:29:848]
[Ti.JavaScript] [Information] Loading JS path=C:\ProgramData\Tide
SDK\modules\win32\network\1.3.1-beta\tinetworkmodule.js [09:32:29:865]
[Ti.Host] [Information] Loaded module = tinetwork [09:32:29:868]
[Ti.Host] [Debug] Loading module: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\
win32\process\1.3.1-beta\tiprocessmodule.js [09:32:29:875]
[Ti.JavaScript] [Information] Loading JS path=C:\ProgramData\Tide
SDK\modules\win32\process\1.3.1-beta\tiprocessmodule.js [09:32:29:886]
[Ti.Host] [Information] Loaded module = tiprocess [09:32:30:071]
[Ti.UI.Win32WebKitPolicyDelegate] [Debug] decidePolicyForMIMEType ()
not implemented [09:32:30:133] [Ti.JavaScript.JSUtil] [Debug]
Evaluating JavaScript file at: C:\
ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\ui\1.3.1-beta\ui.js [09:32:30:458]
[Ti.Proxy] [Debug] Looking up proxy information for: https://api.
appcelerator.net/p/v1/app-track [09:32:30:471] [Ti.Proxy] [Debug]
Using direct connection. [09:32:59:866] [Ti.Database.DB] [Debug] DB
Path = C:\Users\Administrateur\AppDat
a\Roaming\TideSDK\standalone-chatpomelo\Databases.db [09:32:59:875]
[Ti.Database.DB] [Debug] Creating table Origins [09:32:59:878]
[Ti.Database.DB] [Debug] Creating table Databases [09:32:59:883]
[Ti.Database.DB] [Debug] Execute called with create table if not
exists last_check(time long) [09:32:59:889] [Ti.Database.DB] [Debug]
sql returned: 0 rows for result
[09:32:59:893] [Ti.Database.DB] [Debug] Execute called with select strftime('%s'
,'now')-time from last_check
[09:32:59:899] [Ti.Database.DB] [Debug] sql returned: 1 rows for result
```

when i clicked on join button :

```
[09:33:48:758] [Ti.Proxy] [Debug] Looking up proxy information for:
http://127.0 .0.1:3014/socket.io/1/?t=1371029628706 [09:33:48:767]
[Ti.Proxy] [Debug] Using direct connection. [09:33:58:990] [Ti.Proxy]
[Debug] Looking up proxy information for: http://127.0
.0.1:3014/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/CgIVO7gZHpHkKvWon4Nf?t=1371029638938
[09:33:59:000] [Ti.Proxy] [Debug] Using direct connection.
[09:33:59:057] [Ti.API] [Information] [pomeloclient.init] websocket
connected!
```

and nothing else after that ...
Any idea what's the matter ?
I don't know if you can help me or if i have to ask on Pomelo forum ...

Answer (score 1):

Well , i found some errors on tidSDK console :

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Uint8Array js/lib/build/build.js : 709
```

And when i click on the "test server" button :

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'pomelo' [undefined] is not an object. index.html : 24
```

First one seems to be because of the old webkit version used by tideSDK !

I found a compatibility.js file in github pdf.js (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js )
which seems to resolve first issue, but now i have another one :

```
Can't find variable: ArrayBuffer
```

Well, this old webkit version seems very ennoying...
Any idea how to resolve this new error ? 
And the second one ?